# How to define 'action' according to values entered in text bars?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I would like the `<form action` to be set according to the link values I set in text bars (`input`) with name `chart4`, `chart5` and `chart6`.

The idea is to put links in the text bars and when I press the button, this link opens in `iframes`.

I tried to do it as follows:

```
</body>
<input type="text" id="chart1" name="chart1"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart2" name="chart2"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart3" name="chart3"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart4" name="chart4"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart5" name="chart5"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart6" name="chart6"><br>
<p></p>
<form method="post" action= chart4.value target="iframe1">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 1" />
<form method="post" action= chart5.value target="iframe2">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 2" />
<form method="post" action= chart6.value target="iframe3">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 3" />
</form>
<iframe name="iframe1" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe2" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe3" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<p></p>
```

**But in the test nothing happens, how to proceed?**

Complete script if necessary.

```
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
function refreshIt() {
   if (!document.images) return;
   document.images['Gráfico1'].src = chart1.value;
   document.images['Gráfico2'].src = chart2.value;
   document.images['Gráfico3'].src = chart3.value;
   setTimeout(refreshIt,500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
}
//--></script>
</head>

<body onLoad=" setTimeout(refreshIt,500)">

</body>
<input type="text" id="chart1" name="chart1"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart2" name="chart2"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart3" name="chart3"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart4" name="chart4"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart5" name="chart5"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart6" name="chart6"><br>
<p></p>
<form method="post" action= chart4.value target="iframe1">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 1" />
<form method="post" action= chart5.value target="iframe2">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 2" />
<form method="post" action= chart6.value target="iframe3">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 3" />
</form>
<iframe name="iframe1" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe2" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe3" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<p></p>
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico1">
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico2">
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico3">
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action= chart4.value` sets the action of the form to the value of `#chart4`, which at the time is nothing, so there is no action.

Instead, set the action of the iframes inside the `refreshIt` function.

```html
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
function refreshIt() {
   if (!document.images) return;
   document.images['Gráfico1'].src = chart1.value;
   document.images['Gráfico2'].src = chart2.value;
   document.images['Gráfico3'].src = chart3.value;
   iframe1.action = chart4.value;
   iframe2.action = chart5.value;
   iframe3.action = chart6.value;
   setTimeout(refreshIt,500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
}
//--></script>
</head>

<body onLoad=" setTimeout(refreshIt,500)">
<input type="text" id="chart1" name="chart1"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart2" name="chart2"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart3" name="chart3"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart4" name="chart4"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart5" name="chart5"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart6" name="chart6"><br>
<p></p>
<form method="post" target="iframe1">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 1" />
<form method="post" target="iframe2">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 2" />
<form method="post" action= chart6.value target="iframe3">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 3" />
</form>
<iframe name="iframe1" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe2" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe3" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<p></p>
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico1">
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico2">
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico3">
</body>

</html>
```

However, I don't recommend using a `setTimeout` to update the action of the forms. It's better to use an event listener that updates the action everytime the user enters something into the inputs. This reduces the need for useless operations for the browser.

In our case, we can delegate an `input` event listener to all input fields that calls the `refreshIt` function. With this approach we don't need the setTimeout at all.

```html
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
function refreshIt() {
   if (!document.images) return;
   document.images['Gráfico1'].src = chart1.value;
   document.images['Gráfico2'].src = chart2.value;
   document.images['Gráfico3'].src = chart3.value;
   form1.action = chart4.value;
   form2.action = chart5.value;
   form3.action = chart6.value;
}

//--></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="chart1" name="chart1"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart2" name="chart2"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart3" name="chart3"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart4" name="chart4"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart5" name="chart5"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart6" name="chart6"><br>
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(e => e.addEventListener('input', refreshIt));
</script>
<p></p>
<form method="post" id="form1" target="iframe1">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 1" />
</form>
<form method="post"  id="form2" target="iframe2">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 2" />
</form>
<form method="post" id="form3" action= chart6.value target="iframe3">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 3" />
</form>
<iframe name="iframe1" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe2" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe3" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<p></p>
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico1">
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico2">
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico3">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello my friend, when I try to put a link like ```https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png``` and click on the buttons, nothing happens. Could you help me with what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BrondbyIF I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Mate, I'll create a new question for doubts, because some links I'm trying to open are giving error 403, the images placed in text bars 1, 2 and 3 I need to update every half second, of text bars 4, 5 and 6. And I'm going to paste the link to the new question here.

Comment: @BrondbyIF Sure, no problem.

Comment: Hi @Spetric here the link to the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68366627/error-403-when-trying-to-open-link-added-to-text-bar-and-how-auto-update-the-ima