# Error 403 when trying to open link added to text bar and how auto update the images?

Tags: javascript, html, image, iframe

I'm using *Notepad++* to create the script.

When I try to open the [link](https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=21081122) from the text bar and activation button it delivers the `403 error`, but when I set the value directly in `<iframe src="INDICATED LINK"` and open the `HTML` this error doesn't appear and it opens perfectly inside iframe.

[image]

I would also like to know how to update every *0.5 seconds* only the `img` with names `name="Graphic1"`, `name="Graphic2"` and `name="Graphic3"`. How could I separate calls to `iframe` (which don't need to refresh every 0.5 seconds) from calls to `img` that need to refresh automatically every 0.5 seconds?

Script:

```
<html>

<head>
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
function refreshIt() {
   if (!document.images) return;
   document.images['Gráfico1'].src = chart1.value;
   document.images['Gráfico2'].src = chart2.value;
   document.images['Gráfico3'].src = chart3.value;
   iframe1.action = chart4.value;
   iframe2.action = chart5.value;
   iframe3.action = chart6.value;
   setTimeout(refreshIt,500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
}
//--></script>
</head>

<body onLoad=" setTimeout(refreshIt,500)">
<input type="text" id="chart1" name="chart1"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart2" name="chart2"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart3" name="chart3"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart4" name="chart4"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart5" name="chart5"><br>
<input type="text" id="chart6" name="chart6"><br>
<p></p>
<form method="post" target="iframe1">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 1" />
<form method="post" target="iframe2">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 2" />
<form method="post" target="iframe3">
<input type="submit" value="I Frame 3" />
</form>
<iframe name="iframe1" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe2" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe3" width="350" height="282"></iframe>
<p></p>
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico1">
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico2">
<img src="https://logospng.org/download/betfair/logo-betfair-fundo-laranja-1024.png" name="Gráfico3">
</body>

</html>
```

The expected result for `iframe` would be something like (This result is what I get when I use `<iframe src = https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=21081122`):

[image]

Comment: Did you mean it opens fine in the browser but not the iframe? Because in the screenshot you provided it looks like the iframe isn't displaying it properly.

Comment: When I set the iframe value as the cited link and open the html, the page opens perfectly in the iframe, but when I try to open it by placing the link on the button, it's giving error 403.

Comment: For example, when I set ```<iframe src="INDICATED LINK"``` and open the HTML, it's works. But using the button and text bar, doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, the link was pasted wrongly, I updated the question with the correct link.

Comment: *"when I set the value directly in <iframe src="INDICATED LINK" and open the HTML this error doesn't appear and it opens perfectly inside iframe."* - weird. It shows 403 for me when I directly set the `src` to the URL. Does it show it correctly in this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/exjd8su9/

Comment: The result obtained from the link you published, from the game between Club Brugge Utrecht is exactly what I wanted to open in my HTML.

Comment: I see a 403 when I open the fiddle. Is that what you expect to see?

Comment: Please, test in this link to see open: ```https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=21081122``` I will add the question as the result should be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234832/discussion-between-spectric-and-brondby-if).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you're writing bad the link it should be like https://xtsd.betfair.com/... and not like https://sporthttps//xtsd.betfair.com/... as you are writting right now.

And about refreshing the images you do something like this:

```js
 setInterval(() => {
        document.images["Gráfico1"].src = chart1.value
        document.images["Gráfico2"].src = chart2.value
        document.images["Gráfico3"].src = chart3.value
 }, 500)
```

Comment: Sorry, the link was pasted wrongly, I updated the question with the correct link.